# Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack

How can I solve this warning when creating laravel project?

Steps to replicate:

1. composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel example
2. cd example
3. composer require laravel/ui
4. php artisan ui vue --auth
5. npm install vue@next vue-router@next vue-loader@next
6. npm install
7. npm run dev

```
WARNING in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[4]!./resources/sass/app.scss)
  Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
  Warning

(2423:3) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

Child mini-css-extract-plugin C:\xampp\htdocs\lva\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[1]!C:\xampp\htdocs\lva\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[2]!C:\xampp\htdocs\lva\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[3]!C:\xampp\htdocs\lva\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[4]!C:\xampp\htdocs\lva\resources\sass\app.scss compiled with 1 warning
webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try changing `color-adjust` to `print-color-adjust` in your css?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do right now but I don't know what file to change. I searched for `color-adjust` and only 3 files popped up: `app.css`, `prism.css`, `bootstrap.min.css`. I changed them all but still no effect.

Comment: You have change `color-adjust` to `print-color-adjust` in `./resources/sass/app.scss`

Comment: Only `imports` are in the `app.scss`

Comment: Then you will have to check those imports one for one by removing them until the warning is gone.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated and it depends on the autoprefixer@10.4.6 ([source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259)).

I was able to fix this by reverting the autoprefixer package as well as @Benno to version 10.4.5. Run this:

```
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
```

Comment: I had the warning on autoprefixer 10.4.2, but just upgrading to the latest fixed it for me. I don't see anything in the release notes though

Comment: I had notifications/errors with Laravel 9.11 and Jetstream (Tailwind / Livewire), with "npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact" I have no more errors. Thx !

Comment: Worked for me too without needing to add the stats children above.. super thanks! :)

Comment: For further readers, the problem was fixed in Bootstrap 5.2, You can install it (beta) via `npm install bootstrap@next-5`, or wait for the official version to land. Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259#issuecomment-1143073964

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: @FernandoTorres were you creating a fresh project with the lasted version of laravel?

Comment: > its currently deprecated

Does it mean it will be undeprecated soon? Or do we need to change color-adjustment shorthand somewere?

Answer (score 7):

You probably updated your npm packages. I was able to fix this by reverting the autoprefixer package to version 10.4.5 in the package-lock.json.

Answer (score 4):

when you have problem with autoprefixer maybe because your version autoprefixer. you can add version autoprefixer based problem this version [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/blob/10.4.6/CHANGELOG.md) . i have problem on "print-color-adjust" and i add code on my package.json for change my autoprefixer become version "10.4.5"

when you use npm

```
    "overrides": {
      "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
     },
```

Or, when you use yarn

```
    "resolutions": {
      "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
    },
```

Don't forget to delete your package-lock and node_modules , then npm install again.
it work for me (react-bootstrap.v.5)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, whenever I hit save an annoying pop-up of error code comes. The simple solution is to add the following code to your webpack.mixjs file :

```
mix.webpackConfig({
stats: {
    children: true,
},});
```

stop the npm run watch

add a package autoprefixer, add below in terminal:

```
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
```

run npm run watch and it will not give the error again.

Comment: This Didn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add additional packages to solve this error, then try this:

```
Capitalize all the files and Directory name in your components folder
```

Or you can run this command to install a package if the above solution doesn't work.

```
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
```

I'm using `React` with `InertiaJS` and `Laravel` as backend, this solution worked in my case.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue within Laravel by changing the file ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms/_form-check.scss

Line 28 part of the .form-check-input style
change `color-adjust: exact; // Keep themed appearance for print`
to `print-color-adjust: exact; // Keep themed appearance for print`