# Excluding folder while building for production not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, bundler, ts-loader

I have a folder with some mock data in "src/api/mock" folder which contains some ts and JSON files. I want Webpack to exclude them when it builds for production. I tried using the below rule but its not working. Any suggestions?

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|json)$/i,
        exclude: ['/src/api/mock/'],
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude directory from getting bundled by Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059366/how-to-exclude-directory-from-getting-bundled-by-webpack)

Comment: no none of the solutions working for me

Comment: are u using typescript?

Comment: yes, I am using ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  ...others,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|json)$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/api/mock'),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: this causes an error for service worker
1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)

Comment: Let's see whether this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083968/1-warning-in-child-compilations-use-stats-children-true-resp-stats-child

Answer (score 0):

since you are using typescript you should use `tsconfig.json`. when you init this file you should have this already

```
 "exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

Just add the correct path for this '/src/api/mock/' to the array. I think `ts-loader` follows this file's configuration